# What happens in the lifecycle of a fragment if a different fragment is created

Tags: android, fragment, lifecycle

I have a fragmentA and I create a new fragmentB without removing or popping fragmentA. Is fragmentA still active?

Comment: Nothing happens until and unless you remove the existing fragment form the fragment manager or replace with newly created one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Fragments on the same level of the hierarchy just exist in parallel. They don't influence each other.